# PHP Cloning Children

Tags: php, clone

I have an object that is a somewhat basic tree. I needed to make a deep copy of it and found myself implementing the __clone method. The successful code is:

```
function __clone() {
    $object = new CustomXML($this->rootElement);
    foreach ($this->elements as $key => $element) {
        $this->elements[$key] = clone $this->elements[$key];
        $object->elements[$key] = $this->elements[$key];
    }
    $object->attributes = $this->attributes;
    $object->value = $this->value;
    $object->allowHTML = $this->allowHTML;
    $object->endTag = $this->endTag;
    $object->styles = $this->styles;
    $object->childID = $this->childID;

    return $object;
}
```

My question is... Why do I have to use

```
$this->elements[$key] = clone $this->elements[$key];
$object->elements[$key] = $this->elements[$key];
```

Why can't I just use

```
$object->elements[$key] = clone $this->elements[$key];
```

Using the second one still leaves a reference to the children. Why is this? The values in $this->elements are of the same class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__clone()` is invoked on an *already-created shallow copy* of an object. [See the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)

PHP will shallow-copy all properties and create a new object without calling its constructor (similar to serialization and deserialization). Then PHP calls `__clone()` on the *new* object so you can *modify* it according to your whims. Because it *modifies* the object, it should not return anything.

Your code (if you always want a deep copy) should look like this:

```
   function __clone() {
        foreach ($this->children as $key => $child) {
            $this->children[$key] = clone $this->children[$key];
        }
   }
```

However I **strongly recommend that you do not do this**! Instead of relying on the `clone` keyword, add methods to return cloned objects explicitly (e.g., [`DOMNode::cloneNode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.clonenode.php). This will, for example, let you control whether your copies should be shallow or deep. If you just use `clone` you cannot control this.

Here is an example:

```
interface DeepCopyable
{
    /**
     * Return a copy of the current object
     *
     * @param $deep bool If TRUE, return a deep copy
     * @return object
     */
    public function copy($deep=false);
}

class TreeNode implements DeepCopyable
{
    private $I_AM_A_CLONE = false;
    protected $children = array();

    function __clone() {
        $this->I_AM_A_CLONE = true;
    }

    public function addChild(Copyable $child) {
        $this->children[] = $child;
    }

    public function copy($deep=false) {
        $copy = clone $this;
        if ($deep) {
            foreach ($this->children as $n => $child) {
                $copy->children[$n] = $child->copy($deep);
            }
        }
        return $copy;
    }
}


$a = new TreeNode();
$a->addChild(new TreeNode());
var_dump($a);
var_dump($a->copy());
var_dump($a->copy(true));
```

This example also illustrates the *proper* use of `__clone()`. You need to add a clone magic method **when a private or protected property of the cloned object should not be identical to the original**.  For example, if you have an `id` property on an object which should be unique, you may want to ensure that a clone will not have the same ID and you never ever want calling code to control that. Or a "dirty" flag, or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

After a long review of this, I created a test scenario and realized that I was not understanding the clone method at all.

Consider this example code:

```
<?php
    class A {
        function __construct($value = "1") {
            $this->value = $value;
            $this->children = array();
        }

        function addChild() {
            $this->children[] = new A(count($this->children));
        }

        function __clone() {

            foreach ($this->children as $key => $child) {
                $this->children[$key] = clone $this->children[$key];
                //$object->children[$key] = clone $this->children[$key];
            }
        }
    }

    $a = new A();
    $a->addChild();

    $b = clone $a;

    var_dump($b);
    $b->value = "test";
    $b->children[0]->value = "test2";

    var_dump($a);
    var_dump($b);
```

The clone method is **being called on `$b`**, not on $a. So essentially, calling `$this->children[$key] = clone $this->children[$key];` is breaking the reference. Returning a value is pointless here. In summary, my code should have looked like this:

```
foreach ($this->elements as $key => $element) {
    $this->elements[$key] = clone $this->elements[$key];
}
```

You might say that calling `$b = clone $a;` is equivalent to doing:

```
$b = $a;
$b->__clone();
```